# sphinx: removing comments from "show source"

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

Sphinx has a "show source" link to view the RST source:

(example from [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.7.html))

[image]

I want to leave "show source" active, but I would like to put comments in the RST and have them NOT show up in the "show source" results.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: The only clue I am able to provide is that copying of sources to the output is done in the `handle_page()` method of `StandaloneHTMLBuilder` (https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/blob/master/sphinx/builders/html.py). I guess that you'll have to intercept the copy operation and filter out the comments. Somehow.